# Linear layout gets hidden on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/member_80" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setphoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:text="Set Photo"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Hermoine"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Basic"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Joined on Sep,21 2013"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="899 Posts" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/membervotes"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/artist"
        android:background="@drawable/votes_bg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="388"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topformline"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnsettings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topformline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFeaturedDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/notification_icon" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.8dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFeaturedDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/messages_icon" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.8dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnprofile_settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/setting_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomformline"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnsettings"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottomformline"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_btn_gingerbread"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/dialog_start_icon"
                android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
                android:text="Dialogs Started" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_btn_honeycomb"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/dialog_moderated_icon"
                android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
                android:text="Dialogs Moderated" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/bottomformline"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/main_btn_honeycomb"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_btn_honeycomb"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/followers_icon"
                android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
                android:text="Followers" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_btn_gingerbread"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/dialog_argued_icon"
                android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
                android:text="Dialogs Argued" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_btn_honeycomb"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/archive_icon"
                android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
                android:text="Dialogs Archived " />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/bottomformline"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/main_btn_honeycomb"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_btn_honeycomb"
                style="@style/DashboardButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/following_icon"
                android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
                android:text="Following" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is displaying properly in portrait mode but in landscape mode the below linearlayout is hidden(it is not displayed).

Any ideas pls?

Thanks,

Comment: design different layout file for landscape and potrait

Comment: Is there no other solution. It's a whole lot of work.

Comment: AFAIK, layouts are actually supposed to be different for landscape and portrait.. Or you can design any layout using only Relative. There's no need to use Linear IMO.

Comment: Ghost good point @asifa you can use a single relative layout.

Comment: but i think it is in a single relativelayout.

Comment: @asifa you don't need a `LinearLayout` you can use just one single `relativelayout`

Comment: Additionally, I would also suggest this. If you really need a complex looking XML layout, you can delete the `RelativeLayout` and instead keep the entire thing inside another `LinearLayout`. That way, it won't be as messed up. But I would still suggest you to take off the `LinearLayout` and keep only the `RelativeLayout` to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, just guessing: May be your upper view is taking more space and lower view has no space left on screen to show. Try putting your complete view in [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).